# Declaring new instance of structure in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, structure, instance

```
struct xampl {
       int x;
       char y;
};

struct xampl InstaceOfxampl;
struct xampl *PointerToxampl;
struct xampl &new_struct;
```

We are creating a simple instance in first case, and a pointer to structure xampl in second. However what does the third declaration mean? How is it handled differently as compared to other two in code?

Comment: I don't believe the last one is valid C.

Comment: The third "declaration" means a "syntax error" in C. In C++, it is an invalid declaration of a *reference* (you need to initialize it to make it valid).

Comment: Given the name of the question, it seems to bear mentioning that the second declaration does not "create" an instance of struct xampl.  The first declaration results in allocation on the stack of space for a struct xampl instance.  Note that the struct [almost certainly] consists of garbage data.  The second declaration results in allocation on the stack of space for a pointer to a struct xample.  This pointer consists of garbage data as well.  That's to say the address that it points to is garbage.  With the second declaration (sans malloc), it's not possible to access the struct's members.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, `struct xampl &new_struct` declares a reference (however, it is invalid, because a reference have to be initialized). In C, it does not mean anything, here.

Answer (score 0):

you can access a member of the structure:

- first one(structure variable) using a `.`
- second one(structure pointer) using a `->`

you can store the address of the first one in the second one like:

```
PointerToxampl=&InstaceOfxampl;
```

as everybody else said third one is invalid thing to do.if you want to decalre a reference.it should be done as below:

```
struct xampl &new_struct=InstaceOfxampl;
```